# What is the best practice in Android about Upload a Photo with a loading message?

Tags: android, image-uploading

I need upload a photo to server and show a loading message.

I tried with this code but the ProcessDialog works unsteadily...

```
new UploadTask(MainActivity.this).execute(bitmap);
....
private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Long> {                       
   private ProgressDialog dialog = null;        
   private Context context;     
   public UploadTask(Context context){
     this.context = context;
   }        
   protected void onPreExecute() {      
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);           
        this.dialog.show();         
   }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {                    
    if(this.dialog != null){
        this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at splash screen implementations. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Comment: Can you tell us more about "ProcessDialog works unsteadily"?

Comment: Eric, in some occasions processdialog works and another not... :-( i think  that it happens by the cycle life of the MainActivity but not sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to implement an IntentService and notify status with broadcast intents. please checkout complete code from github

Android library that provides an easy to use service to upload files with Android Notification Center integration

https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service

let me know if you facing any problem to integrate this code